# Windows Forms calculating delta mouse movement negative values

Tags: c#, winforms, mousemove

I'm trying to create a simple app to send mouse input over the network to remotely control another machine, using C# and .NET Framework 4.5

I'm having a weird issue when I try to calculate the mouse cursor delta movement in the MouseMove event: below is a sample code I made to isolate this issue:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Point previousPosition;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        previousPosition = MousePosition;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePos = MousePosition;
        int deltaX = (mousePos.X - previousPosition.X);
        int deltaY = (mousePos.Y - previousPosition.Y);


        label1.Text = "X: " + deltaX.ToString() + " Y: " + deltaY.ToString();
        label2.Text = "previousX: " + previousPosition.X + " currentX: " + mousePos.X;

        previousPosition = MousePosition;
    }
}
```

I'm storing the previous cursor position in a class variable and on the MouseMove event I calculate the difference in positions and update the previousPosition variable.

Now the weird thing is that this is working only for positive deltas (when I move the mouse to the right).

I put some labels in the form to show in real time the coordinates and, to my surprise, when i move the cursor left, the previous coordinate and the current one always stays the same, resulting in a zero delta!

Am I missing something stupid and obvious here? Why is the previousPosition variable equal to the MousePosition when I move the cursor left, but when moved right it works as expected?

Comment: Your code works fine, you're only updating things way too fast. If you add a Stopwatch and run the logic only every 500ms or every second, it works as expected. Here's a delayed version so you can see it works http://pastebin.com/xnBKqbB6

Comment: I'm not sure why it's doing this, I guess for some reason, you're getting multiple mouse move events when moving left.. If you add `if (mousePos == previousPosition) return;`, then you get the expected behaviour.

Comment: There are too many move events raised when you move in a negative direction, for every 1 pixel move there are 2 events where the mouse didn't actually move.  Both hor and ver.  Odd quirk, the Windows version surely matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I replicated your issue, and fixed it by adding a check for duplicate move events to the code:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePos = MousePosition;

    if (mousePos == previousPosition)
        return;

    // .. your other code here        

    previousPosition = mousePos;
}
```

I'm not sure why there are multiple mouse-move events for the same position only when moving left.

Comment: Many thanks! I am perplexed now as to why the MouseMove gets called multiple times when moving left. Good to remind that some things happen so fast that the human eye cannot see :)

Comment: As soon as I finish the networking infrastructre to send the movements to other client i will test further if the check is really necessary and post the results here.